# Oracle Apex 4.2 Dynamic action with custom event "beforeunload" not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

So i have created a custom dynamic action that is supposed to run "beforeunload" (in case user closes the tab/browser unexpectedly or navigates away from the page in a manner not intended). This dynamic action runs a simple plsql procedure ( http://prntscr.com/qz0a6c ). A few days ago the Chrome browser updated to version 80 and in this new version "beforeunload" is disallowed and now my dynamic action does not work.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could build this functionality differently?  Apex 4.2 is in question.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: Yes i have...but I don't know how to implement this in apex

Comment: I could probably show you how, but first, please tell me a bit about what the PL/SQL code and the JavaScript code in the actions are doing (I'll need to be sure you can still do it). Also, do you have the ability to create REST APIs in the SQL Workshop?

Comment: Nevermind... I think I have something generic enough for you that doesn't require ORDS. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess you are hitting Disallow sync XHR in page dismissal So to turn
>   your DA to asynchronous one try to set Wait for result property of
>   your dynamic actions to false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete answer that you should be able to adapt to your situation.

1. Create a new table to record send beacon data.

   ```
   create table beacons (
     id        number generated always as identity primary key,
     app_user  varchar2(255),
     date_sent date,
     data      varchar2(4000)
   );
   ```

   I used a varchar2 for the data but that could be a CLOB if needed. I'll be passing the data in using the p_clob_01 parameter for Ajax.
2. Create an Application Process named **RECEIVE_BEACON** in the Shared Components. Use the following code for the PL/SQL code:

   ```
   insert into beacons (
     app_user,
     date_sent,
     data
   ) values (
     :APP_USER,
     sysdate,
     apex_application.g_clob_01
   );
   ```
3. Create a Dynamic Action named **Window beforeunload**. Set **Event** to **Custom**, **Custom Event** to **beforeunload**, **Selection Type** to **JavaScript Expression**, and **JavaScript Expression** to **window**.

   [image]
4. Select the Action for the Dynamic Action created in step 3. Set the **Action** to **Execute JavaScript Code**. Copy/paste the following into the **Code** field.

   ```
   var beaconData = {
     test: 'value'
   };

   var formData = new FormData();

   formData.append('p_flow_id', '&APP_ID.');
   formData.append('p_flow_step_id', '&APP_PAGE_ID.');
   formData.append('p_instance', '&APP_SESSION.');
   formData.append('p_debug', '');
   formData.append('p_request', 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=RECEIVE_BEACON');
   formData.append('p_clob_01', JSON.stringify(beaconData));

   navigator.sendBeacon('/pls/apex/wwv_flow.ajax', formData);
   ```

Save your changes and run the page. Then refresh the page to trigger the Dynamic Action and send the beacon. This example shows how you can send random data from JavaScript but also get session-related data, such as the user name.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough and detailed answer. Even though unchecking "wait for result" on the dynamic action solved my problem i will definitely look into your solution!

Comment: That makes it an asynchronous Ajax request. Be sure to test it with different browsers. This article seems to suggest it may not work with all of them: "Ensuring that data has been sent during the unloading of a document has traditionally been difficult, because user agents typically ignore asynchronous XMLHttpRequests made in an unload handler." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon The solution above uses the `sendBeacon` method, which was built to do what you're doing but isn't supported in IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=sendbeacon

Comment: A little update on this. So my solution was working unreliably. The procedure that runs is a simple delete statement, where i pass an id and it deletes a row from a table with that ID. I saw that it was not deleting rows in a test envirnoment (when I do tests it works every time). So i decided to try out your solution. Got it working (when i test it). But again, in test..i see that it is not deleting rows. Any ideas why it doesn't work 100% of the time? Chrome browser is what all users use.

Comment: So the "test environment" is a group of folks manually testing the app using Chrome? It's not anything automated?

Comment: No it is not automated. The only scenario where I was able to find the DA not firing is if the session times out. Considering how often the rows are not being deleted I doubt this is what is happening all the time.

Comment: It makes sense that the solution doesn't make sense without a valid session, the request would fail. A REST request wouldn't have the same issue, but you may have other security-related problems. And then there's the issue of it not working 100% of the time regardless of the session... Can you tell us more about the business objective you're trying to achieve? Perhaps you could take another approach.

Comment: When a user enters a "product page" it locks the product for editing to other users. If another user enters the same page it will show them a readonly version and a message. When the user leaves the page, the lock is removed.  I have a table that holds some info (product_id, session, user, time-of-lock etc.). There is a process in after header that checks if there is a lock existing. If so show the message and put in readonly. If not put a lock. The before unload is supposed to remove this lock (delete the row from the table) when the user is exiting the screen.

Comment: I see... You're basically trying to simulate a persistent connection to the database. This will be very difficult to do without an assistive technology like WebSockets (say via a Node.js middle tier). That route can get complex fast if it's not already part of your architecture.

Comment: Maybe you could try this approach: 1) When a user navigates to the page, you open it in an edit mode or read-only mode. 2) Either way, when the page opens, you start an Ajax-based ping (say every 5 seconds). If the user is in the edit mode, the ping just verifies that they are still working with the record. If in read-only mode, the ping checks to see if a set amount of time has passed since the last lock was reported (say 15 seconds). If it's determined that the user can edit the page, show a message with a refresh button that will reload the page to attempt to open it in an edit mode.

Comment: Oh wow. That is exactly what I thought of and implemented this morning! And that will have to do for now. Thanks for all your help and time!